# How to totally close all the auto indent

Tags: indentation

In my case, I was writing a tex file. After Closing some auto indent settings

```
set noai noci nosi
filetype indent off
filetype plugin indent off
```

But vim still gave me 2 tab indent when I type `{` or `[` in a 2 level `\begin`, like:

```
\begin{...}
\begin{...}
        {
\end  {...}
\end  {...}
```

It is also shown in the picture, at line:55, the **second** `\umlcreatecall`.

I want no any auto indent, what will create it and how can I close it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @filbranden Yes it is, thanks for a lot.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to the `indentexpr` option being set.

This option is typically set by the indent plug-in connected to the filetype.

You're disabling indent plug-ins with `:filetype indent off`, but you're doing so only *after* having opened a `*.tex` file in Vim. The indent plug-ins (together with filetype detection and filetype plug-ins) are applied when the file is opened, so disabling it after the file is opened will not undo these settings.

You can open Vim with no file open, then disable filetype indent plug-ins with `:filetype indent off` and finally open the `*.tex` file, in which case the indent plug-in will not be loaded and `indentexpr` will not be set.